# Merging config parameters in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, symfony-3.3

I currently fight with Symfony's configuration processing. I want to override certain nested parameters for the dev environment.

My **config.yml** contains:

```
parameters:
    curl:
        return_transfer: true
        timeout: 25
        connect_timeout: 2
```

My **config_dev.yml** contains:

```
parameters:
    curl:
        timeout: 60
```

So, I only want to override one (nested) config parameter "timeout". But I only get this (overridden) parameter in the dev environment container. The other ones (return_transfer and connect_timeout) are gone. It seems that the whole parameter config is replaced and not merged with config.yml. How may a merge these parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parameters` is a single-dimensional array. This means that your `curl` parameter is actually an array of values, not parameters.
I believe you can only duplicate these in your dev parameters.

```
    return_transfer: true
    connect_timeout: 2
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe that's it. Copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have at least the following lines in your 'config_dev.yml`:

`imports:
    - { resource: '../common/config.yml' }`

and be sure your app is being started in --env=dev mode to load the config_dev.yml in a standard Symfony setup.

For details check [Documenation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/configuration_organization.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks. I've already done that and included config.yml in config_dev.yml. And I use the app_dev.php front controller.

Comment: Found similar problem description in https://www.drupal.org/node/2551009

Comment: Unfortunately there is no answer. It is an open issue.

Comment: sometimes that's the answer unfortunately, see @svgrafov's answer as well